Does this equivalence relation on a group $G$ relate to irreducible representations?
Let $G$ be a group.

Irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with conjugacy classes of $G$: $x \sim y \iff \exists_{g\in G}\ x^g = y$ .
Irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with rational conjugacy classes of $G$: $x \sim y \iff \exists_{g\in G, n \in \mathbb{N}}\ x^g = y^n$ where $n$ is coprime to the order of $y$.
Irreducible representations of $G$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with $p-$regular conjugacy classes of $G$: conjugacy classes of $G$ whose order is coprime to $p$.

An irreducible representation of $G$ over $k$ may also be thought of as a simple functor B$G \to \mathrm{Vect}(k)$, with B$G$ the delooping of $G$.
Define an autjugacy class of $G$ to be an equivalence class of elements of $G$ under the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff \exists_{\varphi\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)}\varphi(x) = y$.

Are autjugacy classes of $G$ in one-to-one correspondence with simple functors B$G \to \mathcal{C}$ for some category $\mathcal{C}$?

